# A11y in pure CSS solutions based on `input:checked` pseudo selector

Tags: html, accessibility, pure-css

I came across pure CSS solutions based on the pseudo selector `input:checked`, for example

- https://webdevtrick.com/css-sidebar-menu/
- https://webdevtrick.com/html5-css3-responsive-menu/
- https://webdevtrick.com/pure-css-tabs-responsive/

This solutions are very smooth and clever, the absence of JavaScript is good for performance but what about accessibility?

Comment: I quickly checked your links, and it seems that they aren't screen reader accessible. I can find the checkbox, but when I click on it, nothing appears to happens from my point of view. Jaws 2022 + latest chrome.

Comment: @QuentiC maybe it's something that could be fixed with ARIA attributes?

Comment: Could you please provide some code in your question?

Comment: @nulll: JavaScript is needed to add and handle the appropriate aria-expanded attribute, the checkboxes aren't always well labelled, but beyond that, the problem seem to be more fundamental. I don't find anything appearing or disappearing upon clicking on the checkbox, so for me whether it doesn't work, or I haven't understood what was the purpose / what I'm supposed to find out. Maybe you can explain what the checkboxes are supposed to do in the three live demos ?